# Cancel button in asp.net referal to aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need help in my asp.net project. I have a "Cancel" button on my page. But it does not work. I have a onclick-function that refers it to a specific page, but when i press it, it askes for validation in the boxes on that page. Whats the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this attribute

```
CausesValidation="False"
```

to you Cancel button server side control. This way when the cancel button gets clicked, it will not force validation for the values of your form and you will get what you want.

For further documentation on how this works, please refer to this link:

[How to: Disable Validation for ASP.NET Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt244wbb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)